# WCF service proxy not setting "FieldSpecified" property

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I've got a WCF `DataContract` that looks like the following:

```
namespace MyCompanyName.Services.Wcf
{
  [DataContract(Namespace = "http://mycompanyname/services/wcf")]
  [Serializable]
  public class DataContractBase
  {
    [DataMember]
    public DateTime EditDate { get; set; }

    // code omitted for brevity...
  }
}
```

When I add a reference to this service in Visual Studio, this proxy code is generated:

```
/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "2.0.50727.3082")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://mycompanyname/services/wcf")]
public partial class DataContractBase : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {

    private System.DateTime editDateField;

    private bool editDateFieldSpecified;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=0)]
    public System.DateTime EditDate {
        get {
            return this.editDateField;
        }
        set {
            this.editDateField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("EditDate");
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public bool EditDateSpecified {
        get {
            return this.editDateFieldSpecified;
        }
        set {
            this.editDateFieldSpecified = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("EditDateSpecified");
        }
    }

    // code omitted for brevity...
}
```

As you can see, besides generating a backing property for `EditDate`, an additional `<propertyname>Specified` property is generated. All good, except that when I do the following:

```
DataContractBase myDataContract = new DataContractBase();
myDataContract.EditDate = DateTime.Now;

new MyServiceClient.Update(new UpdateRequest(myDataContract));
```

the `EditDate` was not getting picked up by the endpoint of the service (does not appear in the transmitted XML).

I debugged the code and found that, although I was setting `EditDate`, the `EditDateSpecified` property wasn't being set to `true` as I would expect; hence, the XML serializer was ignoring the value of `EditDate`, even though it's set to a valid value.

As a quick hack I modified the `EditDate` property to look like the following:

```
   /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=0)]
    public System.DateTime EditDate {
        get {
            return this.editDateField;
        }
        set {
            this.editDateField = value;

            // hackhackhack
            if (value != default(System.DateTime))
            {
              this.EditDateSpecified = true;
            }
            // end hackhackhack

            this.RaisePropertyChanged("EditDate");
        }
    }
```

Now the code works as expected, but of course every time I re-generate the proxy, my modifications are lost. I could change the calling code to the following:

```
DataContractBase myDataContract = new DataContractBase();
myDataContract.EditDate = DateTime.Now;
myDataContract.EditDateSpecified = true;

new MyServiceClient.Update(new UpdateRequest(myDataContract));
```

but that also seems like a hack-ish waste of time.

So finally, my question: does anyone have a suggestion on how to get past this unintuitive (and IMO broken) behavior of the Visual Studio service proxy generator, or am I simply missing something?

Comment: Add `[XMLSerializerFormat]` to attributes on your service: Check to this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13396190/wcf-service-method-arguments-bool-specified)

Comment: in case you copy/paste from comment by @MustafaMagdy -- it's `[XmlSerializerFormat]` (note the case)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It might be a bit unintuitive (and caught me off guard and reeling, too!) - but it's the only proper way to handle elements that might or might not be specified in your XML schema.

And it also might seem counter-intuitive that you have to set the `xyzSpecified` flag yourself - but ultimately, this gives you more control, and WCF is all about the [Four Tenets of SOA](http://architectopia.blogspot.com/2008/01/four-tenets-of-soa.html) of being very explicit and clear about your intentions.

So basically - that's the way it is, get used to it :-) There's no way "past" this behavior - it's the way the WCF system was designed, and for good reason, too.

What you always can do is catch and handle the `this.RaisePropertyChanged("EditDate");` event and set the `EditDateSpecified` flag in an event handler for that event.

Comment: would it be a violation to generate a warning when it looks like someone forgot the xyzSpecified?

Comment: Agree this is the answer, disagree this is the only way/good design. This is crap design. They need to offer an option to have these set automatically in the setters for properties for simple use cases.

Answer (score 11):

try this

```
[DataMember(IsRequired=true)]
public DateTime EditDate { get; set; }
```

This should omit the `EditDateSpecified` property since the field is specified as required

Comment: if we add that in our local proxy, won't it be overwritten when the client code is built?

Comment: Your class needs to have [DataContract] too and all other properties need to have [DataMember].

Answer (score 7):

Rather than change the setters of the autogenerated code, you can use an extension class to 'autospecify' (bind the change handler event).  This could have two implementations -- a "lazy" one (`Autospecify`) using reflection to look for *fieldSpecified* based on the property name, rather than listing them all out for each class in some sort of switch statement like `Autonotify`:

### Lazy

```
public static class PropertySpecifiedExtensions
{
    private const string SPECIFIED_SUFFIX = "Specified";

    /// <summary>
    /// Bind the <see cref="INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged"/> handler to automatically set any xxxSpecified fields when a property is changed.  "Lazy" via reflection.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="entity">the entity to bind the autospecify event to</param>
    /// <param name="specifiedSuffix">optionally specify a suffix for the Specified property to set as true on changes</param>
    /// <param name="specifiedPrefix">optionally specify a prefix for the Specified property to set as true on changes</param>
    public static void Autospecify(this INotifyPropertyChanged entity, string specifiedSuffix = SPECIFIED_SUFFIX, string specifiedPrefix = null)
    {
        entity.PropertyChanged += (me, e) =>
        {
            foreach (var pi in me.GetType().GetProperties().Where(o => o.Name == specifiedPrefix + e.PropertyName + specifiedSuffix))
            {
                pi.SetValue(me, true, BindingFlags.SetField | BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, null, null);
            }
        };
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Create a new entity and <see cref="Autospecify"/> its properties when changed
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="specifiedSuffix"></param>
    /// <param name="specifiedPrefix"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static T Create<T>(string specifiedSuffix = SPECIFIED_SUFFIX, string specifiedPrefix = null) where T : INotifyPropertyChanged, new()
    {
        var ret = new T();
        ret.Autospecify(specifiedSuffix, specifiedPrefix);
        return ret;
    }
}
```

This simplifies writing convenience factory methods like:

```
public partial class MyRandomClass 
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Create a new empty instance and <see cref="PropertySpecifiedExtensions.Autospecify"/> its properties when changed
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static MyRandomClass Create()
    {
        return PropertySpecifiedExtensions.Create<MyRandomClass>();
    }
}
```

A downside (other than reflection, meh) is that you have to use the factory method to instantiate your classes or use `.Autospecify` *before* (?) you make any changes to properties with specifiers.

### No Reflection

If you don't like reflection, you could define another extension class + interface:

```
public static class PropertySpecifiedExtensions2
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Bind the <see cref="INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged"/> handler to automatically call each class's <see cref="IAutoNotifyPropertyChanged.Autonotify"/> method on the property name.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="entity">the entity to bind the autospecify event to</param>
    public static void Autonotify(this IAutoNotifyPropertyChanged entity)
    {
        entity.PropertyChanged += (me, e) => ((IAutoNotifyPropertyChanged)me).WhenPropertyChanges(e.PropertyName);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Create a new entity and <see cref="Autonotify"/> it's properties when changed
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static T Create<T>() where T : IAutoNotifyPropertyChanged, new()
    {
        var ret = new T();
        ret.Autonotify();
        return ret;
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Used by <see cref="PropertySpecifiedExtensions.Autonotify"/> to standardize implementation behavior
/// </summary>
public interface IAutoNotifyPropertyChanged : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    void WhenPropertyChanges(string propertyName);
}
```

And then each class themselves defines the behavior:

```
public partial class MyRandomClass: IAutoNotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public void WhenPropertyChanges(string propertyName)
    {
        switch (propertyName)
        {
            case "field1": this.field1Specified = true; return;
            // etc
        }
    }
}
```

The downside to this is, of course, magic strings for property names making refactoring difficult, which you could get around with `Expression` parsing?

Comment: Hi @drzaus do you know why don't they also set the "...FieldSpecified" value, if they are already going the path of raising the "PropertyChanged" event??? In example, if I have a "MyProp" property, and at the end of the "set" block they are raising "this.RaisePropertyChanged("MyProp");", why don't they also set the "myPropFieldSpecified" value???

Comment: @RafaelEnriquez who are 'they'?  Microsoft?  I'm guessing the root problem you describe has something to do with the default T4 templates "they" provided for service proxy generation, but your guess is as good as mine as to why they made it that way...

Answer (score 2):

### Further information

On the MSDN [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a1bca402-cbe1-4233-8eb3-ce01b8cefcd4/parameter-names-ending-with-specified-added-to-web-service-method-call?forum=wcf)

In her answer, Shreesha explains that:

> "Specified" fields are only generated on optional parameters that are structs. (int, datetime, decimal etc). All such variables will have additional variable generated with the name Specified.
>
> This is a way of knowing if a parameter is really passed between the client and the server.
>
> To elaborate, an optional integer, if not passed, would still have the dafault value of 0.  How do you differentiate between this and the one that was actually  passed with a value 0 ? The "specified" field lets you know if the optional integer is passed or not. If the "specified" field is false, the value is not passed across. If it true, the integer is passed.

so essentially, the only way to have these fields set is to set them manually, and if they aren't set to true for a field that has been set, then that field will be missed out in the SOAP message of the web-service call.

What I did in the end was build a method to loop through all the members of the object, and if the property has been set, and if there is a property called **name** _*Specified* then set that to true.

Answer (score 1):

Building on [@drzaus's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1680356/wcf-service-proxy-not-setting-fieldspecified-property#answer-21144944), I've created a factory for these types, with these improvements:

1. Implemented `IDisposable`, to ensure that the event handler is disposed. This allows the use of `using`.
2. Added a cache for the properties retrieved by reflection on the type. This avoids the cost of reflection after the first execution.
3. The `CreateObject()` method accepts an `Action` parameter that allows initialisation of the object, for example by setting properties.

```
internal class SoapRequestObjectFactory<T> : IDisposable where T : class, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private const string SpecifiedSuffix = "Specified";
    private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<Type, PropertyInfo[]> PropertiesCache = [];

    private T? _soapRequest;

    internal T CreateObject(Action<T>? initialisationAction = null)
    {
        _soapRequest = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();

        _soapRequest.PropertyChanged += OnSoapObjectPropertyChanged;

        if (initialisationAction is not null) initialisationAction(_soapRequest);

        return _soapRequest;
    }

    private void OnSoapObjectPropertyChanged(object? sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(sender, nameof(sender));

        var properties = GetProperties(sender.GetType());

        var propertyName = e.PropertyName + SpecifiedSuffix;
        var property = properties.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name == propertyName);
        if (property is null) return;

        property.SetValue(sender, true);
    }

    private static PropertyInfo[] GetProperties(Type type)
    {
        if (PropertiesCache.TryGetValue(type, out var cachedProperties))
            return cachedProperties;

        var properties = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
        PropertiesCache.TryAdd(type, properties);

        return properties;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_soapRequest is not null)
        {
            _soapRequest.PropertyChanged -= OnSoapObjectPropertyChanged;
            _soapRequest = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Example use:

```
using var objectFactory = new SoapRequestObjectFactory<OrderRequest>();
var orderRequest = objectFactory.CreateObject(x =>
{
    x.Id = 123;
    x.Name = "Hello world";
});

// Use the objectRequest object as required here. It will be automatically disposed of.
```

Answer (score 0):

Ian,
Please ignore my previous answers, was explaining how to suck eggs. I've voted to delete them.

Could you tell me which version of Visual Studio you're using, please?

In VS2005 client - in the generated code, I get the `<property>Specified` flags, but no event raised on change of values. To pass data I have to set the  `<property>Specified` flag.

In Visual Web Developer 2008 Express client - in the generated code, I get no `<property>Specified` flags, but I do get the event on change of value.

Seems to me that this functionality has evolved and the Web Dev 2008 is closer to what you're after and is more intuitive, in that you don't need to set flags once you've set a value.

Bowthy

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple project that can modify the setters in generated WCF code for optional properties to automatically set the *Specified flags to true when setting the related value.

https://github.com/b9chris/WcfClean

Obviously there are situations where you want manual control over the *Specified flag so I'm not recommending it to everyone, but in most simple use cases the *Specified flags are just an extra nuisance and automatically setting them saves time, and is often more intuitive.

Note that [Mustafa Magdy's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1680356/wcf-service-proxy-not-setting-fieldspecified-property#comment20121988_1680356) on another answer here will solve this for you IF you control the Web Service publication point. However, I usually don't control the Web Service publication and am just consuming one, and have to cope with the *Specified flags in some simple software where I'd like this automated. Thus this tool.

Answer (score -2):

Change proxy class properties to nullable type

ex :

bool? confirmed

DateTime? checkDate

Comment: With WSDL a element could have both minOccurs="0" and nillable="true", hence you need FieldSpecified