# WCF service method arguments, bool specified

Tags: c#, wcf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [WCF will not return an int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12964759/wcf-will-not-return-an-int)

Trying to consume from my own WCF service like this:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IReturnService
{
    [OperationContract]
    bool GetTransactionList(int lRetailStoreID, int lWorkstationNmbr, int lTaNmbr);
}
```

But when I'm calling the service from the client, I get the error that there's no method `GetTransactionList` with 3 arguments, instead I get this header:

```
myWCF.GetTransactionList(int lRetailStoreID, bool lRetailStoreIDSpecified, 
                         int lWorkstationNmbr, bool lWorkstationNmbrSpecified, 
                         int lTaNmbr, bool lTaNmbrSpecified, 
                         out bool GetTransactionListResult, 
                         out bool GetTransactionListResultSpecified)
```

Anyone knows why is this happening and how to solve it? Let me know if more information is needed.

Comment: Can you add the code you are using to call the server?  Is it a generated client?

Comment: Does your client proxy has the same definition as of the server?

Comment: Asked and answered here http://stackoverflow.com/q/12964759/1045728

Comment: As said in the above link are you trying to add the web reference of your WCF service. If so then remove that and add it via Service reference.

Comment: @Rajesh working at VS2005, no "service reference" option

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Add XMLSerializerFormat to attributes on your service:

```
[ServiceContract]
[XmlSerializerFormat]
public interface IReturnService{
...
```

Heres why: http://nirajrules.wordpress.com/2009/08/26/wcf-serializers-xmlserializer-vs-datacontratserializer-vs-netdatacontractserializer/

Comment: That just solved! Thanks