# How to fire RaisePropertyChanged from within a setter

Tags: c#, mvvm

I have a property defined with no explicit mention of backing field in a way like this :

```
//How to fire RaisePropertyChanged("Name") from setter
public string Name { get; set; }
```

How exactly do I fire a RaisePropertyChanged event in the setter of this property ? 
I know how to do it when there is a private backing field and with a public property encapsulating it.

Is a multi line setter allowed in this scenario ?

Comment: You can't have a body in either the getter or setter of an auto-property, you'll need to introduce a backing field.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13663719/avoid-calling-raisepropertychanged-in-every-setter

Answer (score 4):

No, you can't do this with an automatic property. You'll need to have a backing field and define both the getter and setter yourself, and raise the event in the setter as you described.

Comment: +1 because it is true without a lot of tricks. You can do it with reflection though...

Comment: @MichaC Not just reflection but code emission, no? I'm assuming the OP doesn't want to go there ;) BUT if so I do have experience with this..!

Answer (score 0):

That's an Automatic Property, you need to have a backing field.

```
private string _name;
public string Name
{
    get { return name; }
    set 
    { 
        name = value; 
        RaisePropertyChanged("Name"); 
    }
}
```