# c# cannot check if property is not set

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, variables, properties

Background:

1. [WCF service proxy not setting "FieldSpecified" property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1680356/wcf-service-proxy-not-setting-fieldspecified-property)
2. [MSDN Forums: parameter-names-ending-with-specified-added-to-web-service-method-call?forum=wcf](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a1bca402-cbe1-4233-8eb3-ce01b8cefcd4/parameter-names-ending-with-specified-added-to-web-service-method-call?forum=wcf)

I am fed up with having to manually set dozens of "_Specified" fields in my web-service client (for `Struct` datatypes like **Long** and **DateTime**), so I thought I'd try looping through all of the properties in my Soap Body and if it's a Boolean called Specified AND if the property (such as a Birthdate) has been set, then I could default that property to true.

So I wrote this code to loop through, and check if the property isn't null then if not, set the corresponding *Specified* property to true:

```
    Type type = wsSoapBody.GetType();

    PropertyInfo[] properties = type.GetProperties();

    foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
    {
        foreach (var pi in wsSoapBody.GetType().GetProperties().Where(o => o.Name == property.Name + "Specified"))
        {
            if (property != null)
            {
                pi.SetValue(wsSoapBody, true, BindingFlags.SetField | BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, null, null);
            }
        }            
    }
```

Unfortunately, even if some properties haven't been set, `property != null` is always true, so even when a field has not been set, this Boolean value is being set to true, and that's not what I want.

How could I do this properly?

**EDIT**:

to clarify, say I have a field in my soap body type called `Birthdate` (which is a datetime) then in WCF web-service client proxy there will also be a property called `BirthDateSpecified` and that is what I need to set to **true** if `BirthDate` has been set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are checking if property info is not *null*, not the value of property.You need to get property value using [`GetValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.getvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method then check whether it is null.

```
if (property.GetValue(wsSoapBody,null) != null))
{
    pi.SetValue(wsSoapBody, true, BindingFlags.SetField | BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, null, null);
}
```

Comment: so wouldn't that be `if (property.GetValue(wsSoapBody,null) != null)` as I need to check if the property is  null, rather than *propertySpecified* ?

Comment: @OurManInBananas you wanna set the property if the value is null, right?  then it should be `==` not `!=`. and you should get the value of `pi` not `property` if I'm not missing something.

Comment: well, `pi` should be the *propertySpecified* Boolean value, I only want to set that if the property it is specifying is populated. So for example, if `BirthDate` is specified, then I need to set `BirthDateSpecified=true` ...

Comment: @OurManInBananas okey then it should be `if (property.GetValue(wsSoapBody,null) != null)`